# bundler: fetch partial git repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I have a Rails project that contains a `my_gem` folder at root:

```
my_repo
├── app
├── config
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── db
├── lib
├── log
├── my_gem <-- the gem folder
├── public
├── Rakefile
├── README.md
├── script
├── test
├── tmp
└── vendor
```

I use this gem in another project by adding these lines to it's Gemfile:

```
git 'git@gitlab.mydomain.com:qosenergy/my_repo.git', :branch => 'master' do
  gem 'my_gem'
end
```

It works perfectly except that all the repo is fetched, that represents hundreds of megabytes (vs less than 1Mo for the only `my_gem` folder) and this is problematic when I build docker images from the repo that uses the gem: because more than 60% of the image size is filled by the full rails app contained in `my_repo`.

How could I keep the advantage of this behavior but keep only the `my_gem` folder instead of the complete repo ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.12/git.html) it seems that you can fetch one or more gems inside a given repository.

E.g. The [Rails repo](https://github.com/rails/rails) contains several gems: actioncable, actionmailer, actionpack ...

> Specify that a git repository containing multiple .gemspec files
>   should be treated as a gem source
>
> ```
> git 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git' do
>   gem 'railties'
>   gem 'action_pack'
>   gem 'active_model'
> end
> ```

If your `my_gem` contained in the project has a given `.gemspec`, you should be able to install it without downloading the full application where it is contained. If you have done it this way, you might consider other options.

**Git sparse checkout**

Git provides the feature of [sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree/#_sparse_checkout) for cloning only a given path inside the repo. 
You can read [this blog](https://lakehanne.github.io/git-sparse-checkout) for a few use cases:

```
$ mkdir pcl-examples
$ cd pcl-examples                               #make a directory we want to copy folders to
$ git init                                      #initialize the empty local repo
$ git remote add origin -f https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl.git     #add the remote origin
$ git config core.sparsecheckout true           #very crucial. this is where we tell git we are checking out specifics
$ echo "examples/*" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout" #recursively checkout examples folder
$ git pull --depth=2 origin master          #go only 2 depths down the examples directory
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/600189/5687152) is probably making this concept even clearer but I did not figure out how to take advantage of it inside a `Gemfile`.

**Other debugging**

Since you are building a Docker image, you can refer to this [checklist](https://runnable.com/docker/rails/building-your-docker-image) about rails errors. However it seems that you are not experiencing any error, but only an image size issue.

**A couple of clean solution**

I guess the cleanest solution to your issue would be to extract the gem code inside a new repository and install it as you were trying to do. I would personally go for this solution.

If you really don't want to take it out, you could give a try to [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) inside your original project. This approach can be very tricky and even [Github](https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules) is not really encouraging it.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. sparse checkout seems to retreive all the repo in the metadata, it just affects the "visible" files. I won't split the gem to another repo, we use a lot of branches so we'll have to create two branches each time (1 for the main repo & 1 for the gem repo). We also work with submodules but it's too heavy and mistakable. I'm trying a solution: use the ci to build gem archive and put it in a dedicated repo that would be a submodule (or subtree) of the project the uses this gem (placed in vendor/cache to be used by bundler)